# Color Gradients

Tags: computer-science

Say I have two Red Green Blue colors (255, 26, 26) and (241, 232, 91) respectively. If I'd like to determine the color halfway between these two colors, how could I solve for it? Is the answer simply the average of each individual color value, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you do find the average of each of the color channels. There is another type of 'half-way between' for colors, that is half-way between the hues, but since it seems that this effect is not what you're looking for, the average method seems like the most relevant one. If you wish to prove that this is the case, open up your favorite graphics program that can handle gradients, and create one from (241,24,24) to (24,241,24) and check what the center pixel's color is. It should be (133,133,24). This is the average of each color channel.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check you gamma value. The average will be correct only with a gamma of 1 (linear).

The best way is to transform your RGB values in CIE XYZ, the you make the average in XYZ, then you retransform in RGB et voilà!

But make sure your gamma is correct when you transform in XYZ, otherwise it'll not work.

formulae here : easyrgb.com

in RGB to XYZ, the gamma value is after the exponent (^)

Best